# Database Index not used if the where criteria is !=?

Tags: sql, database

I have a index on a column and it is correctly used when the query is

```
select * from Table where x = 'somestring'
```

However it seems to be not used when the query is something like

```
select * from Table where x != 'someotherstring'
```

Is this normal or am I missing something else in the query? The actual query is of course much larger and so it could be caused by some other factor. Any other ideas why an index would not be used in a query?

Comment: What would you hope to gain by using an index with this query?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is normal. Index will only be used if you have a '=' condition. Searching index for != condition is not effective.

Similarly, this may use the index (in Oracle)

```
select * from Table where x like 'some%'
```

but this wouldn't

```
select * from Table where x like '%thing%'
```

Also,
`select * from Table where x between 1 and 10`  will use the index

but not 
`select * from Table where x not between  1 and 10`

Comment: Looking at the one of the answers below, I have experience in mostly Oracle. I'm answering from that perspective.

Comment: Generalizing on this specific case a little bit, it IS possible to be too clever, and get in the way of the optimization engine. Even if you have an index on a column, the query optimizer will not always choose to use it. If you think the optimizer is making a mistake, you can go all "Tom Kyte" on your query, and gather some empirical evidence. If the evidence tells you changes will improve your query, you can use subtle rewrites and, in Oracle's case, "hints" to force the optimizer's hand.

Comment: This is not right, its depends on the data cardinality, as the optimizer will decide if the index cost is better than a scan with where statement, so if the number of records for "someotherstring" is huge, it will work too, but if not the optimizer decides that it does not worth it and switch to scan with where.

Answer (score 3):

this is absolutely normal. index is used to look for exact something. where you start when I ask you to look a dictionary when I told you not start with 'S'.

you can always do this.

```
select * from Table a
where not exist (select * from table b where x = 'somestring' and a.key = b.key)
```

Comment: Would that be faster a full table scan? Because doing the x = 'somestring' is fast, but doing "where not exist" is almost as slow as full table scan anyway?

Answer (score 3):

It may use index if the index is clustering and there are not so many different values of the indexed attribute (so we can quickly decide which blocks we may skip). But if the indexed attribute is, say, a key then using index in this case makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 2):

That is indeed normal - to use the index, you need to use a exact match (like the "=" equals operator), or something like a range query.

A query that defines a "negative" criteria (*NOT* something or another) typically can't be satisfied by an index lookup - you'll have to look up everything except a certain value. That doesn't work nicely - typically, a full table scan (clustered index scan in SQL Server) will be quicker, just checking for the criteria to be matched (or not matched, in that case).

Answer (score 1):

I think that a != condition can use an index (in MSSQL). According the the execution plan in MSSQL, if I have an index on a single field, and I apply a where clause on that field, one with a != and one with =, they both result the same execution plan, both using an index seek.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what database engine you are using.

MS SQL Server, for example, has both `Equality indexes` and `Inequality indexes`.
The latter are used when the `not equal` operator is in play.

Comment: There is definitely no such thing as 'equality' and 'inequality' indexes in Sql Server, any version. Not sure what you may be referring to?

Comment: Yeah. My fault. What I was referring to is that the query planner detects both equality and inequality use of fields; indexes does not distinguish between the two cases but, in my experience, they are used by both kinds of operators. (eg: SELECT statement, equality_columns, inequality_columns FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_details; will show missing indexes from the query planner)