# Primary key not equal zero reduce performance

Tags: sql, oracle

Does primary key not equal zero `id != 0` in `where` clause reduce query performance? Does this checking prevent taking the advantage of `index`ing?

Comment: '!=' is not considered as a good approach w.r.t query optimization/performance. As it leads towards full table scan.

Comment: No it dose not you will be specifying a serch which have no point where primay key is almost always > 0. you are reducing a search instead. but if there is primary key ==0 and you dont wont it then sure it will make a better performance time becouse the row wont be rendered.

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed is it because of the operator `!=` or the value `0`?

Comment: [Here][1] is a detailed discussion on my opinion.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155650/authoritative-source-that-and-are-identical-in-performance-in-sql-server

Comment: I disagree with most of the comments here. If it's a primary key, adding a predicate like `id != 0` will make no discernible difference to the query performance either way. Oracle might use the index or it might not; but this won't be impacted by this predicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Does primary key not equal zero id != 0 in where clause reduce query
>   performance?

It does in the way that you end up with a full table scan.

> Does this checking prevent taking the advantage of indexing?

Yes. Since `id != 0` will almost always evaluate to true you end up retrieving all of the table data.

The less % of the results you're returning, the more likely it is for Oracle to take advantage of your index. Your condition is returning all of your data therefore it isn't taking advantage of your index.

If you're wondering whether you can improve your query performance with the condition `!= 0` the answer is you can't. It's already good enough. Sometimes you have to accept the full table scans, you can't always take advantage of your index.

Comment: is it because of the operator `!=` or the value `0`?

Comment: just to clarify, if it was a non zero value - `id != x` where `x` is non zero positive number, it will still scan the full table?

Comment: That's up to the optimizer. How many rows are `x` ? If a lot of the rows are `x` it will use the index. If _every_ row is different than `x` then it makes sense to scan the whole table, doesn't it?

Comment: *If a lot of the rows are x it will use the index* - I guess it will not use the index according to this - [Q/A, `!=` operator can not take the advantage of index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759476/database-index-not-used-if-the-where-criteria-is).

Comment: there's an answer in that Q/A that says this _It may use index if the index is clustering and there are not so many different values of the indexed attribute_. It's really just an edge case. It will generally not use it because it's rare for the majority of the rows to have the same value.

Comment: It's important with these sorts of questions ("will this make my query slower?") is to consider what the alternative is. In this case, the column is a primary key, therefore the values are not null, and it has a unique index. Adding the inequality predicate will not affect the query performance either way. Removing the predicate will not cause it to use the index and get faster.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp How will it not get impacted? Indexes provide faster access to data for operations that return a small portion of a table's rows. If the condition returns less data, it'll use the index and get faster. Is that wrong?

Comment: An **inequality** predicate on a unique column like this is not very selective at all, so the index is unlikely to confer any benefit; in fact, if you hinted Oracle to use the index, it would probably make the query slower.

Answer (score 0):

if it not equal to zero it going to match with all true condition that id!=0
use **explain** keyword before query (**sql select keyword**) to  check the query performance .
if you want to match multiple records that having value of id 
use **IN key word** .